# Optimized way to perform canvas draw on child region of a master bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

Currently, I have a custom view where it needs to draw itself on a child region, of a master bitmap.

The master bitmap size is larger than the drawing region of custom view. Currently, this is how my code looks like. Although it works, I feel there should be a way to further optimized it.

```
// Code in a custom View
private fun getBitmap(): Bitmap {
    val resources = context.resources

    // Creating a larger master bitmap.
    val screenWidth = resources.getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    val screenHeight = resources.getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    val masterBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val masterCanvas = Canvas(masterBitmap)
    masterCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)

    // Creating a smaller child bitmap.
    val childBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            masterBitmap,
            (screenWidth-width) shr 1,
            (screenHeight-height) shr 1,
            width,
            height
    )

    // Perform drawing on smaller child bitmap.
    val childCanvas = Canvas(childBitmap)
    draw(childCanvas)

    // Copy the smaller child bitmap back to larger master bitmap.
    masterCanvas.drawBitmap(
            childBitmap,
            ((screenWidth-width) shr 1).toFloat(),
            ((screenHeight-height) shr 1).toFloat(),
            Paint()
    )
}
```

So, the step can be summarized as follow

1. Creating a larger master bitmap.
2. Creating a smaller child bitmap.
3. Perform drawing on smaller child bitmap.
4. Copy the smaller child bitmap back to larger master bitmap.

I was wondering, is there a way to eliminate **step 4 :  Copy the smaller child bitmap back to larger master bitmap.** ?

Is it possible to create a child bitmap, which its data memory region directly shared the same data memory region of master bitmap? As, `Bitmap.createBitmap` will create a new instance of Bitmap, with newly allocated memory.

My desired steps are

1. Creating a larger master bitmap.
2. Creating a smaller child bitmap, by mapping directly to larger master bitmap.
3. Perform drawing on smaller child bitmap. This will immediately affect larger master bitmap during child bitmap drawing process.

I was wondering, is there any API enables me to **Creating a smaller child bitmap, by mapping directly to larger master bitmap.** ?